# NotificationCenter not fired with network change

Tags: swift

I want to detect network changes. For example when switching from wifi to 4G or back. But my code doesn't detect these changes. I get only some output when the app has started.

I have this code:

```
import ReachabilitySwift

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let reachability = Reachability()!


        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged),name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,object: reachability)
        do{
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        }catch{
            print("could not start reachability notifier")
        }

    }

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

        if reachability.isReachable {
            if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {
                print("Reachable via WiFi")
            } else {
                print("Reachable via Cellular")
            }
        } else {
            print("Network not reachable")
        }
    }
```

Did I have implemented something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action method takes a parameter so the selector must be

```
#selector(reachabilityChanged(_:)) // self is not needed
```

And the method itself is supposed to be

```
func reachabilityChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
```

Comment: I have changed the code to yours. But it isn't working.

Comment: Try the block-based API.

Comment: What do you mean? I have used example - notifications on this page: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Comment: Fixed. I have added reachability out of the scope.

Comment: Reachability has notification-based and block(closure)-based API

Answer (score 0):

Selector is wrong

change this

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged),name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,object: reachability)
```

to

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(_:),name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,object: reachability)
```

I hope this will work.

and also

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
```

to

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. The function is not getting called when changing the network.

Comment: Edited, please check.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is wrong. Change

```
name: ReachabilityChangedNotification
```

to

```
name: NSNotification.Name.reachabilityChanged
```

or to

```
name: .reachabilityChanged
```

It will work.